# Grails: Incorrect integer value: '¬í' for column 'scenarioId' at row 1

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

This is by far the strangest issue I've encountered with Grails & GORM.

Setup as follows

```
class Scenario{ List connections = [] ... static hasMany=[connections:Connection]}

class Connection{ Scenario scenario; belongsTo=Scenario }
```

When saving a scenario with multiple connections set with data binding. Looking at the variables everything looks fine. The data is bound and all objects appear right.
Then I get this exception:

```
 Incorrect integer value: '¬í' for column 'scenarioId' at row 1
```

which is a java.sql.SQLException.

This is so bizarre! I'm definately sure that the scenario id is not ¬í, it's an integer so how could it even?!

Grails pro's it looks like I need help!

Edit: I checked the sql log and it appears the scenarioId is inserted as a VARBINARY which is wrong. No idea why it tries to do this...

Comment: What version of Grails?  And can you add the code you use to create Scenario that's causing the error?

Comment: 2.0 The code is nothing special. I'm binding the data so it's just scenario.properties = params; scenario.save() But check the edit...

Comment: Can you share your code that is throwing this exception?

Comment: Yes, I already said. it's just scenario.save() that is causing the exception.

Comment: On the `Connection` class do you need to declare `Scenario scenario` or do you just need `static belongsTo = [scenario:Scenario]` by itself?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when attempting to insert an hibernate entity in database.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '¬í' for column 'person' at row 1
```

My problem was that in my entity, i had define a column like this:

```
@Column(name = "person", nullable = false)
private Person person;
```

But it should have be define like that:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person", nullable = false)
private Person person;
```

The problem was that when inserting my entity in database, hibernate was attempting to insert the Object `Person` in place of the id field from `Person`.

Maybe your problem is the same kind of problem ? In place of inserting an integer, it insert a string conversion of your entity.